# Is the generalized Erdős–Heilbronn problem true for finite cyclic groups?

Tags: co.combinatorics, additive-combinatorics, reference-request

The [generalized Erdős–Heilbronn (GEH) theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restricted_sumset), which is proved by da Silva and Hamidoune in 1994, states that:

**Theorem.** If p is a prime and $X$ is a subset of $\mathbb{Z}_p$, then $|\hat{k}X| \geq \min \lbrace k|X|-k^2+1 , p \rbrace$ for $\hat{k}X = \lbrace x_1+\ldots+x_k \mid x_i \in X , x_i \neq x_j \rbrace$.

Also, for the case that $k=2$ (which is called the Erdős–Heilbronn problem), the above statement holds for $X$ as a subset of any finite group $G$; the result is [proved](http://jeffreypaulwheeler.com/Final%20Erdos-Heilbronn_Problem.pdf) by Balister and Wheeler in 2009.

> **Problem 1.** Is the generalized Erdős–Heilbronn problem also true for any finite groups? In particular, is it true for finite cyclic groups?

This question is inspired by the construction of a [counter-example to some variants of Ramsey theorem](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3795/extensions-of-ramseys-theorem-monochromatic-but-diverse/3803#3803). In the construction we may not need the full strength of the GEH, so a related question is:

> **Problem 2.** Is there any weaker results to the GEH, which have already been proved?

Comment: Sorry, what's $d$ here?

Comment: Oh, I see, presumably it's $p$.

Comment: oops, they should be p. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arithmetic progressions usually give small sumsets so...How about $X=\lbrace 0,3,6,9,12 \rbrace \subset \mathbb{Z}_{15}$? Then for $k=2,3,4$ one has $\hat{k}X=X$. That is ok for $k=4$  but not for $k=2,3$. (Doesn't that contradict what you said about $k=2$?)

In fact $X=\lbrace 0,d,2d,\cdots,nd\rbrace \subset \mathbb{Z}_{nd+d}$ for $n \ge 5$ is always a counter-example for $k=3$.

The same type of examples should work as well for larger $k$ and should also work with a few elements removed.

**later** One can't hope for better than $|\hat{k}X| \geq \min \lbrace k|X|-k^2+1 , |H| \rbrace$ where $H$ is the subgroup generated by $X$. After all, $\hat{k}X \subset H$.  I don't know if that is true though. A weaker claim, which seems somewhat more likely, is to replace $|H|$ by the size of the smallest subgroup of size at least $|X|$. I have not read the Balister and Wheeler paper you mention but it seems (from the review posted) to  replace $|H|$ with the size of the smallest non-trivial subgroup, which would be prime of cyclic order.

Comment: Oh, so the GEH for cyclic group HAS to be weaken... Thank you for the nice example! Any idea on the weaker results?

Comment: @Aaron: For the case of $k=2$, we have to replace $p$ with the smallest prime divided $n$, as you mentioned in the edited part. And this is indeed a great answer, many thanks for your thoughtful observations and ideas!